How to understand logging in our application
Our application uses,
For normal logging (.log) : log4j2 supported by log4j-core.jar, log4j-api.jar, log4j2-extensions.jar
For console logging (.out) : log4j (1.2) because we have jboss that uses log4j 1.2 as well. I am assuming this because this is what I see in the log4j.jar MANIFEST file.
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Implementation-Title: JBoss [Trinity]
Implementation-Version: 4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=20
 0707131605)
Specification-Vendor: JBoss (http://www.jboss.org/)
Specification-Title: JBoss
Implementation-Vendor-Id: http://www.jboss.org/
Created-By: ari-49095-20050826-1856-linux-ia32 (BEA Systems, Inc.)
Specification-Version: 4.2.1.GA
Implementation-URL: http://www.jboss.org/
Implementation-Vendor: JBoss Inc.

We also have slf4j-api.jar (2.0.7)
Now, my question is we recently added a shaded thirdparty (TP1.jar) jar that uses slf4j-api (2.0). But in their shaded dir I can also see some classes related to SLF4j within JCL dir. Not sure how they are related ?

So to enable the logging from slf4j from this TP1.jar, I tried adding log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar but it did not work. WHY ?
So I tried with slf4j-log4j12.jar (1.6.1) and it did start logging in our console (.out) log file. And it was complaining as expected :
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:xxx]

But HOW did the logging still happen ?
Now I have another thirdparty jar (TP2.jar) which uses SLF4j as well and does not work with slf4j-log4j12.jar (1.6.1) and only works with 2.x. Why is the problem thirdparty jar specific ?

Voting is anonymous here by design. Some commenters do not explain their downvotes as they fear retaliation. For folks who receive a single downvote, commenting to ask why someone downvoted is not worth the effort. The downvoter will be long gone.

The issue was that, jboss-client.jar was ahead in the application classpath and had a shaded slf4j-api.jar which was 1.x version. So the slf4j-api.jar (2.x) which comes later in the classpath was not being considered. So effectively the application had slf4j-api.jar 1.x.
